# QAbstractItemModel canDrag

Tags: c++, qt

I have tree widget (QTreeView) and reimplement QAbstractItemModel in my ObjectListWidget.
In the tree I have 3 types of objects.
I reimplemented drag-drop functions for this and it works.
But I want to reject drag options for the different types of objects in the tree.
How can I do it? I tried to set dragEnabled(false) on onSelectionChanged, but it works strange (it changes my selection mode to MultiSelection) and diselects items.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you implemented drag & drop.

### QStandardItemModel

If you are relying on `QStandardItemModel`, then you should know the flags:

```
Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled
Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled
```

Now simply set flags ONLY where required, I mean not to all, like:

```
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTreeView>

// ...

QStandardItem *createItem(const QString &name)
{
    auto *item = new QStandardItem(name);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    item->setFlags(flags);
    return item;
}

QStandardItem *createContainerItem(const QString &name)
{
    auto *result = createItem(name);
    auto flags = result->flags();

    flags |= Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;

    result->setFlags(flags);
    return result;
}

QStandardItem *createDraggableItem(const QString &name)
{
    auto *result = createItem(name);
    auto flags = result->flags();

    flags |= Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;

    result->setFlags(flags);
    return result;
}

void testUsage() {
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *window = new QWidget();

    auto *list1 = createContainerItem("My Draggable Content");
    list1->appendRow(createDraggableItem("Item 1"));
    list1->appendRow(createDraggableItem("Item 2"));
    list1->appendRow(createDraggableItem("Item 3"));

    auto *list2 = createContainerItem("My Other List");
    list2->appendRow(createItem("Item 4"));
    list2->appendRow(createItem("Item 5"));

    auto *model = new QStandardItemModel(window);
    model->appendRow(list1);
    model->appendRow(list2);
    auto *rootItem = model->invisibleRootItem();
    rootItem->setFlags(rootItem->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled);

    auto *view = new QTreeView(window);
    view->setModel(model);
    view->setRootIsDecorated(true);
    view->setDragEnabled(true);
    view->setAcceptDrops(true);
    view->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
    view->expandAll();
    

    window->setCentralWidget(view);
    window->resize(300, 400);
    window->show();
}
```